# if two features correlate exactly to the target variable, how does Decision Tree choose between them as the root node to split?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, cart

I have a dataset, that consists of three columns, A,B and X.

A and B are the feature columns and X is the target column. They are all numerical values. I am trying to predict which feature contributed to X.

The dataset is as follows

```
A B X
1 1 0
2 2 1
2 2 1
2 2 1
1 1 0
```

Features A and B are in direct correlation with our target X. On what basis does the [Decision Tree Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) manage to choose the root node?

I have a case, where it always chooses `A` as the root node, instead of `B` when `B` should be the root node. I am trying to understand how does it do that so I can find a solution for the problem.

Comment: If they are in direct correlation with your target, why is there a preference on which one to choose as the root node?

Comment: @adrin the feature name is what matters

Comment: could you elaborate? it's really not clear why you'd prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

I not sure which `Splitter` is used in that example, but basically, it finds the first best improvement it can possibly have as a splitter.

The relevant code looks like [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L482):

```
if current_proxy_improvement > best_proxy_improvement:
    best_proxy_improvement = current_proxy_improvement
    current.threshold = (Xf[p - 1] + Xf[p]) / 2.0

    if current.threshold == Xf[p]:
        current.threshold = Xf[p - 1]

    best = current  # copy
```

This means a new one is chosen if it's strictly better than the older improvement. If in the source you change the `if current_proxy_improvement > best_proxy_improvement:` to `if current_proxy_improvement >= best_proxy_improvement:`, then it'll choose the last one.